# Form_for update action using ajax not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm learning ajax in rails by create a simple app to manage *product* as *datatable*. Anything (***new,create,edit***) did very well  until ***update***.
My submit button in ***update form*** do nothing while i click it.
Here is my terminal log

```
Started GET "/products/3/edit" for ::1 at 2019-05-01 01:14:47 +0700
Processing by ProductsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:68
  Rendering products/edit.js.erb
  Rendered products/_editform.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered products/edit.js.erb (14.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 31.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

products_controller.rb

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }        
        format.js
else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

_product.html.erb

```
<tr>    
    <td colspan="3"> <%= product.id %></td>
    <td colspan="3"> <%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product), remote:true, class:'edit-btn' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

_editform.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
<tr>            
    <td colspan="3"><%= product.id %></td>
    <td colspan="3"><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= f.submit "Save", class: 'save-btn' %></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

edit.js.erb

```
$('.edit-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').html('<%= j render 'editform', product: @product %>');
});
```

update.js.erb

```
    $('.save-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {

       $(this).closest('tr').html('<%= j render 'product', product: @product %>');

});
```

I think the *update.js.erb* have issue. Because when i adding `console.log('hello');`
at top both ***update*** and ***edit*** but only ***edit*** work.
And `network` just show `edit -> status 200`.
Thank you for help

Comment: To submit an ajax form you will want to add the `remote` option: `form_for @product, remote: true`, and make sure you have [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) required by your `application.js`.
This is probably not the full solution, since your server should receive a request anyway. Can you check the browser's network, see if a request was sent?

Comment: @MatthieuLibeer Tks for your support. When I add `jquery-rails` gem, `//= require jquery` and  `//= require jquery-ujs`, i get the error: `couldn't find file 'jquery-ujs' with type 'application/javascript'`. So I back to the last time (included jquery CDN) then add `remote: true` to the form. Actually, I have added `remote:true` before. But it will make the `edit` request status change to `304`, and `update` still not send any request. I'm try replace `form_for` by `form_with`,  or add `url, controller, method option` to the form, it still not help me

Answer (score 0):

updated: I'm find out the error. In my `_editform.html.erb`, Rails form inside the `<tr>` will not render html exactly. `</form>` dont wrap the `text_field` and `submit` button. That's why submit button dont do anything.